# Пробелы в URL

Tags: url, php

Приветствую.

Есть GET-запрос, который хранит URL вида: site.com/example/227172/Text+othertext

Но после попытки получения данного GET-запроса, URL преобразуется в такой вид: site.com/example/227172/Text othertext. То есть, куда-то отбрасывает знак "+", как можно исправить это?

Comment: [`urlencode()`][1]

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @Johny, пробовал, получается вообще каша: %2Fexample%2F203172%2FText+othertext

Comment: А, ну если плюс и тут остается, то тогда `rawurlencode()`

Перед получением сделаете `rawurldecode()`

Comment: Просто сам знак "+" заменяет пробел при кодировании.

Comment: @Johny, сделал так:

$get = rawurlencode($_GET['id']);

Получается так: %2Fexample%2F175132829%2Ftext%20othertext

Соответственно, не парсится страницы ;(

Comment: @Johny, может, просто заменить через str_replace? Не вижу других вариантов пока что.

Comment: nu a esli potom pereobrazovat probeli v +?

Comment: @evansive, вы бы могли ваш код показать?

Answer (score 1):

Параметры GET обрабатываются urldecode(). Urldecode() декодирует любые %## кодированные последовательности в данной строке. *Символ "плюс" ('+') декодируется в символ пробела.*

Если вы попытаетесь получить site.com/example/227172/Text%**2B**othertext, то в итоге получите site.com/example/227172/Text+othertext

Вот одно из решений проблемы:

```
$string = $_GET['str']
$string = urlencode($string);
$string = str_replace("+", "%2B",$string);
$string = urldecode($string);
```

И второе:

```
$string = $_GET['str']
$string = urlencode($string);
$string = rawurldecode($string);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не сработает как есть, потому что знак + нужно обрабатывать до отправки GET запроса, а не после. На сервер вместо символа + уже приходит пробел. index.php?name=test+++end, получим test   end.