# В параметре GET-запроса символ "+" преобразовывается в пробел

Tags: php, html

В параметре GET-запроса символ `+` преобразовывается в пробел.
У клиента в заголовке `"Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` есть.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Всегда так было. Используйте `%2B` для плюса

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261123/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-url

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var string = encodeURIComponent('string+++++');
```